# Multiple Selectors when not called JQUERY

Tags: jquery, image, slide

Been trying out some Jquery and just got an error I really can't understand.

I'm trying slide in images when they are shown on the screen.
This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/4uxoesra/

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var windowTopPos, windowBotPos;

    $.fn.revealOnScroll = function () {
        return this.each(function () {

            if (!$(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
                $(this).hide("slide", {
                    direction: "left"
                }, 1).addClass("hidden");
            }

            objectOffset = $(this).offset().top;

            if (windowBotPos > objectOffset && !$(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {
                $(this).show("slide", {
                    direction: "left"
                }, 5000).addClass("animation-complete");
            }
        });

    }

    $(window).scroll(function () {

        windowTopPos = $(window).scrollTop();
        windowBotPos = ($(window).height() + windowTopPos);

        $('#status').html(windowBotPos);

        $('img').revealOnScroll();
    });

});
```

The problem is, when one is shown, everyone are being shown, at the same time.
This is not what my code say, or is it? Can you see the problem?

Comment: One problem is that you bypassed this site's rules by ignoring its warning message about posting a jsFiddle link without putting any code in your OP.

Comment: and another thing, you didn't specify the exact problem....

Comment: It appears that your object offset is the same for all three images.. which doesn't make sense. Will investigate

Comment: I'm sorry about the JsFiddle link and no code. Didn't really get what they meant with that code.. Well, I'm not as educated as all of you guys here. I'm thankful for the help though. Have a good day/night :)

Comment: I appreciate that.  We certainly don't expect a new user to know everything, which is why [the help section](http://stackoverflow.com/help) is so comprehensive.  Thank-you for your future cooperation.

Answer (score 1):

Your offset will be incorrect if the image is hidden.

Rather, move your `.hide()` to right before you show the element.

```
if (!$(this).hasClass("hidden")) {
       $(this).addClass("hidden");
}

objectOffset = $(this).offset().top;

if (windowBotPos > objectOffset && !$(this).hasClass("animation-complete")) {
       $(this).hide("slide", {
            direction: "left"
       }, 1, function(){
            $(this).show("slide", {
                    direction: "left"
                }, 5000).addClass("animation-complete");
            });
       }
});
```

See the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xvb9nc8e/1